Avoid contents in M-x term to be shown out of the window
Table of contents

The problem
The question
Appendix: Install and use font 5x7.bdf
Appendix: My minimal Emacs configuration

NOTE: This post contains many screenshots of the graphical interface of Emacs with a very small font. If content of the screenshots is difficult to read, you can open the images in a new tab by clicking on "Open Image In New Tab" in your web browser and zoom in.
Sorry for the long post, but I feel it is necessary.

My use case
I work with different scripts from different languages in Emacs, some of these scripts contain characters with minimal details. For example, consider the following pairs of similar characters from the devanagari script: नम or the han script: 璧壁, 镱镜 and 畲畬. In order to easily different those characters, I display them with a big size using a OpenType font. To accomplish this behavior, I use the following sexps:
(set-fontset-font t 'devanagari (font-spec :family "Noto Sans Devanagari" :size 50))
(set-fontset-font t 'han (font-spec :family "Noto Sans CJK SC" :size 50))

In contrast to characters from the devanagari or han script, I don't need to display ASCII characters with a very big font size because ASCII characters can be easily differentiated, so I use an small bitmap font for ASCII characters. The reason I use a small font is that by doing so the most number of lines fit on my screen, so I can read the most information without having to scroll. This is particularly useful when reading content that mostly involves ASCII characters (e.g. docker logs inspecting the source code of GNU projects). The reason I use a bitmap font is that a small bitmap font is easier to read than an small OpenType font. The bitmap font that I use is 5x7.bdf from the misc misc font (see Appendix below for instructions on downloading and using it). To use 5x7.bdf, I use the sexp shown above.
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Fixed" :height 59)
(set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Fixed" :size 7))

You can see how the line height varies across different lines in the screenshot below. (line-pixel-height) can be used to get the height of each line.
Devanagari (देवनागरी)   नमस्ते / नमस्कार (line-pixel-height) => 66
Chinese (中文,普通话,汉语) 你好 (line-pixel-height) => 73
This is a line containing characters for which glyphs exist in 5x7.bdf: AZ19┃• (line-pixel-height) => 7


When I feel tired, I sometimes decide to use a big font for ASCII characters because it helps me to focus when I don't feel I have enough energy to focus.
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Noto Sans Mono" :height 150)

Devanagari (देवनागरी)   नमस्ते / नमस्कार (line-pixel-height) => 66
Chinese (中文,普通话,汉语) 你好 (line-pixel-height) => 73
This is a line containing characters for which glyphs exist in 5x7.bdf: AZ19┃• (line-pixel-height) => 24


When Emacs tries to display a character that doesn't belong to the scripts devanagari or han and the font 5x7.bdf doesn't define a glyph for that character, Emacs tries to use any other font available in my system to display that character.
I use M-x term as my terminal emulator. Inside the *terminal* window, I run tmux and I have configured the tmux status bar to be shown at the top (I used set-option -g status-position top in the tmux configuration for setting this behavior). When I use the *terminal* window, I always use 5x7.bdf. The screenshot below shows tmux being run in M-x term. The green line at the top is the tmux status bar.

Most of my work inside terminal involves using ASCII characters, but sometimes characters that belong to the scripts han and devanagari are shown in the terminal. This is where the problem arises.

The problem
As I mentioned earlier, character from the devanagari script or han script are displayed using a big font, so when those characters are shown in the *terminal* buffer, the height of the lines in which those characters are shown is greater than the other lines that only contain ASCII characters. Because the height of the lines are different, some content at the top of the *terminal* window is displayed out of the borders of the window, for example the tmux status bar at the top disappears (see 1st screenshot below). That's undesirable behavior. The visibility of the tmux status bar shouldn't depend on the content that is being shown. In other words, it should always be visible just as happens when tmux is being run in other terminal emulators such as gnome-terminal (see 2nd screenshot below) and kitty (see 3rd screenshot below). It seems to me that that gnome-terminal and kitty assign the same height to each line and try to fit any character within that height.
I created a file containing many lines that contains one devanagari character to demonstrate the behavior:
rm -f /tmp/a.txt && for i in $(seq 1 100); do echo "$i न" >> /tmp/a.txt; done

The screenshot below shows the behavior in Emacs' M-x term when printing the contents of /tmp/a.txt. Note that the tmux status bar at the top disappears.

The screenshot below shows the behavior in kitty when printing the contents of /tmp/a.txt. Note that the tmux status bar at the top doesn't disappear.

The screenshot below shows the behavior in gnome-terminal when printing the contents of /tmp/a.txt. Note that the tmux status bar at the top doesn't disappear.

Characters that don't belong to devanagari and han script or for which 5x7.bdf doesn't define a glyph also cause the same problem. Emacs tries to use any other available font to display those characters, so it is possible that the used font is bigger than the default font being used. Thus, also making some content in the *terminal* window to be out of the borders of the window (i.e. the tmux status bar at the top is not shown anymore.) To demonstrate this behavior, I created a file that has 100 lines containing a character that doesn't belong to devanagari and han and for which 5x7.bdf doesn't define a glyph for.
(line-pixel-height) reports 12 in the lines that have the ⟳ character. I used (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) (describe-char-display is defined in descr-text.el) to get the font that is used for that character, it returned "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-medium-normal-semicondensed-*-12-*-*-*-c-60-iso10646-1 (#xE11)" which corresponds to the file 6x12.bdf. I don't want to use 6x12.bdf, I want to use 5x7.bdf so that the height of all lines is 7 and more lines fit in my screen.
rm -f /tmp/a.txt && for i in $(seq 1 100); do echo "$i ⟳" >> /tmp/a.txt; done


This problem also occurs in vterm because the fundamental problem is that lines might have different heights. Initially, I had thought this issue had to do with vterm, so I opened an issue in the repository, now I know I was wrong.

The question
How to avoid the tmux status bar at the top in a *terminal* window from disappearing due to lines having bigger height than other lines?
The possible solution I have came up with are:

Define a minor mode which when enabled prompts the user for a font and make Emacs use that and only that for the current buffer. Characters that are not defined by the font should be displayed as glyphless characters (for example, empty boxes), thus all lines will have the same height. This mode should also affect those characters for which specific fonts have been set through set-fontset-font, for example if the user set the font for the han script as I did before: (set-fontset-font t 'han (font-spec :family "Noto Sans CJK SC" :size 50)), that rule should be overwritten in the buffer where this minor mode has been enabled and if the user's selected font don't have glyphs for han characters, then han characters should be shown as empty boxes. Other buffers where this minor mode hasn't been enabled should honour the rule (set-fontset-font t 'han (font-spec :family "Noto Sans CJK SC" :size 50)).

Most of my work inside *terminal* involves working with ASCII characters, so I wouldn't mind if characters belonging to the devanagari or han script are shown as empty boxes, even when this happens I could disable the minor mode to see their meaning (which would make the tmux status bar at the top to disappear) and enable the minor mode again (which would make the tmux status bar to remain at the top again.)


Use 5x7.bdf in kitty or gnome-terminal. Although kitty and gnome-terminal don't support bitmap fonts, fonttosfnt can be used to convert a *.bdf file to a *.ttf file by running $ fonttosfnt -o /tmp/5x7.ttf ~/Downloads/misc-misc-master/5x7.bdf.

Using a terminal emulator inside Emacs would be more convenient though.



Other solutions are welcome. The constraints of my setup are:

Characters from different scripts (e.g. devanagari or han) might be shown with different font sizes
Use the font 5x7.bdf as the default font. I can change the default font at any point in time
Show the tmux status bar at the top and it should never disappear
Use a terminal emulator inside Emacs


Appendix: Install and use font 5x7.bdf
In Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, these .bdf files are available under the package xfonts-base. This package is installed by default and the files are stored in /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/.
The file 5x7.bdf can also be downloaded at this Gitlab repository. If you download the repository and copy the .bdf files to ~/.fonts, and run fc-cache -f and use fc-list to list the available fonts, you will notice that the font family of all of those files is the same: Fixed (see code block below).
$ fc-list |  grep -i '\.bdf'
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/9x15B.bdf: Fixed:style=Bold
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/6x13O.bdf: Fixed:style=Oblique SemiCondensed
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/8x13.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/6x13B.bdf: Fixed:style=Bold SemiCondensed
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/7x13B.bdf: Fixed:style=Bold
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/7x14B.bdf: Fixed:style=Bold
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/6x9.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/10x20.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/12x13ja.bdf: Fixed:style=ja
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/5x8.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/5x7.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/6x10.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/4x6.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/9x15.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/8x13O.bdf: Fixed:style=Oblique
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/9x18.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/7x13O.bdf: Fixed:style=Oblique
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/18x18ja.bdf: Fixed:style=ja
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/18x18ko.bdf: Fixed:style=ko
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/7x14.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/7x13.bdf: Fixed:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/6x13.bdf: Fixed:style=SemiCondensed
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/6x12.bdf: Fixed:style=SemiCondensed
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/8x13B.bdf: Fixed:style=Bold
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/9x18B.bdf: Fixed:style=Bold
$ echo $?
0

I was able to use the font 5x7.bdf by setting :family to Fixed and :height to 59 as shown in the sexp below. Through trial and error, I found out that the range [59, 67] for :height made Emacs use 5x7.bdf as the default font. Setting :height to 58 made Emacs use 4x6.bdf as the default font and setting :height to 68 made Emacs use 5x8.bdf as the default font.
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Fixed" :height 59)

A (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-regular-normal-normal-*-7-*-*-*-c-50-iso10646-1 (#x42)"
Z (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-regular-normal-normal-*-7-*-*-*-c-50-iso10646-1 (#x5B)"
1 (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-regular-normal-normal-*-7-*-*-*-c-50-iso10646-1 (#x32)"
9 (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-regular-normal-normal-*-7-*-*-*-c-50-iso10646-1 (#x3A)"

Although 5x7.bdf defines glyphs for the code points • (hex: U+2022, int: 8226) and ┃ (hex: U+2503, int: 9475), Emacs won't use 5x7.bdf  for those characters. See what (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) reports other fonts for those characters when the font has been set using (set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Fixed" :height 59).
A (line-pixel-height) => 7 (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-regular-normal-normal-*-7-*-*-*-c-50-iso10646-1 (#x42)"
• (line-pixel-height) => 13 (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-medium-oblique-normal-*-13-*-*-*-c-80-iso10646-1 (#x482)"
┃ (line-pixel-height) => 13 (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-medium-normal-normal-ja-13-*-*-*-c-120-iso10646-1 (#x48A)"


I could make Emacs use 5x7.bdf for the characters • and ┃ using the sexp below (see first code block below). Upon evaluation of the sexp, (line-pixel-height) returned 8 for hte lines containing those characters (see second code block below.)
(set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Fixed" :size 7))

A (line-pixel-height) => 7 (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-regular-normal-normal-*-7-*-*-*-c-50-iso10646-1 (#x42)"
• (line-pixel-height) => 7 (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-regular-normal-normal-*-7-*-*-*-c-50-iso10646-1 (#x489)"
┃ (line-pixel-height) => 7 (describe-char-display (point) (char-after)) => "ftcrhb:-Misc-Fixed-regular-normal-normal-*-7-*-*-*-c-50-iso10646-1 (#x567)"



Appendix: My minimal Emacs configuration
The following code block contains the relevant part of my configuration related to this issue.
 ;; Use 5x7.bdf at startup.
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Fixed" :height 59)
;; Use 5x7.bdf for characters in the symbol script. See "Appendix:
;; Install and use font 5x7.bdf" for the importance of this sexp.
(set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Fixed" :size 7))
;; Set font for characters in the script devanagari
(set-fontset-font t 'devanagari (font-spec :family "Noto Sans Devanagari" :size 50))
;; Set font for characters in the script han
(set-fontset-font t 'han (font-spec :family "Noto Sans CJK SC" :size 50))

(define-minor-mode my-use-big-font-minor-mode
  "Use a big font as the default font."
  :global t
  (if my-use-big-font-minor-mode
      (progn
        (when my-use-small-font-minor-mode
          (setq my-use-small-font-minor-mode nil))
        (set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Noto Sans Mono" :height 150))
    ;; When my-use-big-font-minor-mode is disabled, use my-use-small-font-minor-mode
    (my-use-small-font-minor-mode 1)))

(define-minor-mode my-use-small-font-minor-mode
  "Use a small font as the default font."
  :global t
  (if my-use-small-font-minor-mode
      (progn
        (when my-use-big-font-minor-mode
          (setq my-use-big-font-minor-mode nil))
        (set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Fixed" :height 59))
    ;; When my-use-small-font-minor-mode is disabled, use my-use-big-font-minor-mode
    (my-use-big-font-minor-mode 1)))

